# How to get the login user name in JSp?

Tags: jsp

I need to get the users Loging name  from  NTLM .
Any one who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FAQ](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1045412)

```
String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");
if (auth == null)
{
  response.setStatus(response.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
  response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
  response.flushBuffer();
  return;
}
```

Comment: thanks you....
i run this code but it does not give me the user name...
I want the user name?
if u have the code for the same,can you please share the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}
```

OR

```
${pageContext.request.remoteUser}
```